# Passing an int array of variable length as a function parameter in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, function, parameters

I have the following code which works fine...

```
int testarr[3][3] = {
  {1,1,1},
  {1,0,1},
  {1,1,1}
};   
[self testCall: testarr];
```

Which calls this function:

```
- (void)testCall: (int[3][3]) arr {

    NSLog(@"cell value is %u",arr[1][1]);
}
```

I need the array to be of variable length - What is the best way to declare the function?

Using blanks doesn't work:

```
- (void)testCall: (int[][]) arr {
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
- (void) testCall: (int *) aMatrice;
```

Doing so allows you to avoid multiple mallocs and the math to calculate a single offset in a linear array based on x, y coordinates in a 2D array is trivial.   It also avoids the multiple mallocs implied by int** and the limitations of 2D array syntax perpetuated by the language.

So, if you wanted a 4x5 array, you might do:

```
#define WIDTH 4
#define HEIGHT 5
#define INDEXOF(x,y) ((y*WIDTH) + x)

int *myArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5 * ELEMS_PER_ROW);
```

You could then initialize the array linearly or with a nested for loop:

```
for(int x=0; x<width; x++)
    for(int y=0; y<height; y++)
        myArray[INDEXOF(x,y)] = ... some value ...;
```

And you would pass it to the method like:

```
[foo testCall: myArray];
```

Though you might want to also carry along the width and the height or, better yet, create a IntMatrix subclass of NSObject that wraps all of the pointer arithmetic and storage beyond a nice clean API.

(all code typed into SO)

Comment: Don't forget to `free()` the memory after calling `[foo testCall: myArray];`.

Answer (score 3):

C arrays can't be variable in more than one dimension.

You can't have this:

```
int testarr[][] = {
  {1,1,1},
  {1,0,1,2},
  {1,1}
};
```

But you can have this:

```
int testarr[][3] = {
  {1,1,1},
  {1,0,1},
  {1,1,1},
  {4,5,6},
  {7,8,9}
}

foo(testarr);

void foo(int param[][3])
{
    printf("%d", param[3][1]); // prints 5
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `int[][]` because the size of the second dimension affects how the array is laid out in memory.  If you know the second dimension you can use `int[][x]`, otherwise you'll have to use `int**` which can be accessed just like an array.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` with `NSInteger`s? Those array classes are of variable length, and much easier to use.

This would result in

```
- (void)testCall: (NSArray *) arr {
    NSLog(@"cell value is %u", [[arr objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:1]);
}
```

(Of course, you would also have to define testarr using NSArray.)

If you *really* want to use C arrays, making the method argument a pointer to an int with

`- (void)testCall: (int*) arr {`

will probably work (with the rest of the code staying the same).

Comment: The OP would need to use `(int **)` to get a two dimensional array.

Comment: You can't put NSIntegers in an NSArray since NSInteger isn't an object, it's just a typedef of some kind of int.  You'd have to use NSNumber, which would introduce some overhead.

Comment: Chris, (int**) means a pointer to a pointer to an int, not a pointer to a two-dimensional array.  Adding an indirection has nothing to do with the layout of the memory you're referencing.

Answer (score 0):

call

```
int testarr[3][3] = {
  {1,1,1},
  {1,0,1},
  {1,1,1}
};   
[self testCall: (int *)testarr];
```

function

```
- (void)testCall: (int *) arr 
{
    int (*V_arr)[3] = (int(*)[3])arr;
    NSLog(@"cell value is %u",V_arr[1][1]);
}
```