# Properly declare 2D array of Ints

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode

I'm trying to declare this initialized variable in my Objective-C program. I want it to be private and reference it in my implementation file. However, when I placed this in the .m file, I get an error saying "Array has incomplete element type 'int []'"

So, question is where am I supposed to place this and what is the correct syntax? I want my variable's syntax to be close to C as possible.

```
int evaluationTable[][] = {{3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3},
    {4, 6, 8, 10, 8, 6, 4},
    {5, 8, 11, 13, 11, 8, 5},
    {5, 8, 11, 13, 11, 8, 5},
    {4, 6, 8, 10, 8, 6, 4},
    {3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3}};
```

Comment: Saw that question already; didn't help much.

Comment: I'm not sure why; it contains exactly the information you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1402352/603977